# how can I set the web size in css?

Tags: html, css

I want to increase the overall size of the page. The current webpage looks too small for the screen size.  please let me know how to make the homepage appear full on the screen like a normal website.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaDp2.jpg)

this is my code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>

    <style>
       
    
        html, body{
            width: 1920px;
            height: 2476px;
            background: black;
            opacity: 1;
            margin: 0 auto;
            border: 1pt solid white;
            
            
        }
        header{
            width: 1920px;
            height: 200px;
            background: black;
            opacity: 1;
            margin: 0 auto;
            border: 1pt solid white;
        }
        header h1{
            color: aliceblue;
            text-align: center
        }
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <header> <h1>HEADER</h1> </header>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove `width: 1920px` from them?

Answer (score 0):

You've set the `body` and `header` width at 1920px.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 2476px;
  background: black;
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1pt solid white;
}

header {
  height: 200px;
  background: black;
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1pt solid white;
}

header h1 {
  color: aliceblue;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>HEADER</h1>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put
'''
max-width:100%;
height:auto;
Instead of width: 1920px;
In the body.
And then put in the header
max-Width:100%
instead of width:1920px